# Android NDK: Dalvik Heap and Native Heap - How Separate Between the two

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk, dalvik

I know there's Dalvik(JVM) heap and Native heap in an android platform.
And the Dalvik GC has no work on native heap.
But I'm not sure how this work, I mean how the Android OS separate them?

possible situation 1: composed by separate memory hardware (I don't believe much)

possible situation 2: Android OS has FIXED amount of memory for both heap

possible situation 3: Android OS has to allocate part of Dalvik memory heap to become native heap when necessary, and so the size of native heap and Dalvik heap is flexible.

Which one is true, or possibility that I didn't mention?

Answer (score 10):

The native heap is managed by `dlmalloc()`, which uses a combination of `mmap()` and standard calls like `sbrk()` to allocate memory.  The managed ("Dalvik") heap is (mostly) one large chunk allocated with `mmap()`.  It's all running on top of the Linux kernel, so if you understand Linux memory management then you already know how the lower-level parts work.

You can read more about how Dalvik returns empty pages from the managed heap to the OS in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049715/do-dalvik-vm-processes-release-system-ram/).

**Edit:** the canonical post for information about Android memory management is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android).  I don't think it directly answers your question, but it has a lot of good information and links to informative sites.

Comment: I don't understand much Linux memory management or Android OS lower-level parts much. Do you have any link that gives an introduction to it?

Comment: I don't have a site to recommend.  To some extent, where you start is going to depend on how much you already know about malloc/sbrk/mmap, virtual memory, and how precise an answer you need.  To get a very precise answer you'd need to read the code and understand it.  For a less precise answer I can say, "heaps are separate, Dalvik heap size is capped, native heap has no fixed limit; the Dalvik heap cap is per-process, not per-device".

Comment: You said native heap has no limit, so does native heap used up dalvik memory when needed more memory space?

Comment: (Still in less-precise answer mode) No, you just run out of memory if you request too much.

Comment: i know, but would native heap use up memory space that had assign to dalvik heap when more native memory is needed?

Answer (score 3):

Since Android is open source, you can [check out the source code yourself](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/alloc/HeapSource.cpp). Looks like it calls `create_mspace_with_base()`. I'm not exactly sure what that does, but according to [this post](http://myresearch-exe.blogspot.com/2010/07/dalvik-memory-management.html), it maps memory from `/dev/zero`.

So it really is using a "separate" heap. It allocates its own memory pages directly and manages that itself.

Answer (score 3):

**It is almost your second case**

There are 2 separate `heaps`, one for the `runtime` `Art`(previously `DalvikVM`), and one for the `native` programs.

You can easily see these two different areas by performing a `cat` on the `maps` pseudo-file of the `proc` filesystem.

Consider the following output:

```
2a028000-2a029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b6400000-b6c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
```

In the above example, the first area, that is only 1 page long, it is managed by the `ART Runtime`. Both `dlmalloc` and `rosalloc` are supported, but `ART` uses `rosalloc` since it is faster. This area, in contrast to what @fadden said (at least for Lollipop), is managed by `sbrk`. It grows `upwards`.

The second area, that is `2048` pages long, it is the `native heap`. It is used by the `bionic` library, which is an implementation of `libc` for Android. Both `dlmalloc` and `jemalloc` are supported, and the one that it is being used depends on the device. I haven't found a call that extends this heap, but I guess `mmap` would suffice. It grows `downwards`, towards the `runtime` heap.

Comment: ~"cat on the maps pseudo-file of the proc filesystem".  What is the full command? `cat /proc/meminfo`?

Comment: `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` (replacing `<pid>` with `self` will give you the maps file for the cat command that you will be running)

Comment: It seems that the [heap] vma is not managed by ART runtime, and what fadden says ART runtime use a large trunk of memory is right indeed.